# How can I open an image file from a dialogue box in Python 3?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to create a simple interface from which user can select images to take as input. THen I am using numpy and opencv to do things on the image. I have used askopenfilename() from tkinter and fileopenbox from easygui. 
They don't seem to return an image.

The error I get is:`TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`

My code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import easygui

face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('face.xml')
def todo():
    img = easygui.fileopenbox()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 7, 7)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]


        cv.imshow('img',img)
        cv.waitKey(0)
        cv.destroyAllWindows()

todo()
```

Comment: sharing what you did will help us help you :)

Comment: Edited the original post.

Comment: Dialog boxes usually return the filename or a handler to the file, not the file contents. Check what's the type of the `img` variable.

Comment: @Azazel have a look at the answer. The line returned a Unicode object which needed to be converted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because you were passing a Unicode object to be read as an image file. The line `img = easygui.fileopenbox()` returned `img` as a Unicode **not** an image array as expected.

#### How do you convert this?

- First convert the unicode to a string. There is a library, `unicodedata`for just this purpose. (I have shown how to use it in the code below)
- Next read this string and store the resulting image file as an array.

The following code will help you out

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import easygui
import unicodedata

path = 'C:/Users/Jackson/Desktop/Stack/face_detection/'
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

uni_img = easygui.fileopenbox()
img_path = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', uni_img).encode('ascii','ignore')

img = cv2.imread(img_path, 1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]


cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### UPDATE:

I have made necessary modifications to the code provided by you. Just copy the following and execute it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import easygui

face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('face.xml')
def todo():

    #--- returns the Unicode ---
    uni_code = easygui.fileopenbox()

    #--- converting unicode to string ---
    img_path = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', uni_code).encode('ascii','ignore')
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, 1)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 7, 7)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]


        cv.imshow('img',img)
        cv.waitKey(0)
        cv.destroyAllWindows()

todo()
```

Comment: Sorry for being late...I lost some necessary files..so couldn't execute your code before. After executing your code I get error:unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',uni_code).encode('ascii','ignore')
NameError: name 'unicodedata' is not defined

Comment: Fixed that one. Now get a new error  img = cv2.imread(img_path, 1)
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation

Comment: what does `print img_path` give you?

Comment: For an image called b.jpg it gives b'/home/bot/Desktop/env/b.jpg'

Comment: Are you running on Linux? What type is `img_path`? To know that do: `print(type(img_path))`

Comment: Yeah on linux. Type gives me <class 'bytes'>

Comment: search for how to convert it to a string. When you convert it to a string it will return `/home/bot/Desktop/env/b.jpg`, this can be passed into `cv2.imread()`.

Comment: If it is getting complex just remove the `b` form the front and pass `/home/bot/Desktop/env/b.jpg` to `cv2.imread()`.

Comment: Did it. Now works.Added this:    img_path=img_path.decode("utf-8") before cv.imread

Comment: @Azazel Thanks to you I got to know `easygui` and `unicodedata` !